# libmad - gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fforce-mem'

Tags: rhel, vlc

I am in the process of compiling VLC from source on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. When configuring VLC I get a message that states that I need 'libmad'.

[image]

Downloaded the 'libmad' source code from ftp://ftp.mars.org/pub/mpeg/

[image]

So I unzip the 'libmad' code and run `./configure` and there are no errors. When I run `make` I get an error about an unrecognized command line option.

[image]

What does this error mean? Is this just a typo perhaps? Ultimately I am building VLC from source and need this dependency to build the application. Does anybody know how to troubleshoot or fix this error?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015747/gccs-fforce-mem-option the -fforce-mem option was removed in gcc 4.3, around 2008.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, you pointed me in the right direction, I was able to build 'libmad', thanks! That question links to http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/libmad.html which is what I followed and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The -fforce-mem option has been removed because it has had no effect in the last few GCC releases.

---

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015747/gccs-fforce-mem-option

Since it does not really have an effect, you can go edit the **Makefile** and remove all the no longer used `--fforce-mem` tags. Then, the make should run witout it.

Alternatively, you can use a newer version of the libmad library (If it yet existed, and if you did not download the latest version).

---

Additional info and source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835803/gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-fforce-mem